# How can I have multiple bundles with common dependencies with Vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I work on a project which is based on a Vite.js monorepo and it has 3 types of generated packages (through vite.js lib mode) :

- the core one
- a theme
- a package containing the specific app to run
  The theme and the package to load are set through dynamic url parameters (ie http://localhost:8000/?theme=themeA&pkg=pkgA).

Each package has its own dependencies and common dependencies (defined through peerDependencies), except for the core one which only has own dependencies (ie. React).
Due to some external constraints these packages are loaded in an app which is not in the monorepo, and should be vanilla html/js.

I exclude peerDependencies from each package by listing them in the external option of vite/rollup.

I tried to do this with the umd output format, by having a script in the html/js app which load required bundles by injecting a script tag in the browser. The issue is that dependencies are not exposed for every bundles to use them.
For instance, while the core package loads correctly, the theme fails as React is not defined (React is a dependency of the core package). I can't find a way to do this and ask the umd output to define each dependency globally so that they can be used by every bundle.